# Creation for excel file in classic asp

Tags: excel, asp-classic, xls

I created a excel file in classic asp with the following code.

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = TRUE
objExcel.Workbooks.Add

Set objWorksheet = objExcel.Worksheets("Sheet2")
objWorksheet.Activate

objWorksheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = "A"
```

I have got the following error.

```
Microsoft Office Excel (0x800A03EC)
Microsoft Office Excel cannot open or save any more documents because there is not enough available memory or disk space. • To make more memory available, close workbooks or programs you no longer need. • To free disk space, delete files you no longer need from the disk you are saving to.
```

How can I solve this? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try these guys? http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/officeappcompat/thread/2c753037-4600-4a4f-abd7-d228e2f20a38  and  http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/microsoft-excel-cannot-open-or-save-any-more/ab1a73d9-1666-4cf5-a6a7-285d2004dd08

Answer (score 3):

Instead of creating an instance of Excel to create the file (an approach I've always found to leak memory and ultimately fail from Classic ASP), I'd suggest you consider outputting the data as a big HTML table, and force the browser to open it in Excel using the following at the start of your response:

```
<%
response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
response.AppendHeader "content-disposition", " filename=export.xls"
%>
```

Comment: Actually, it's "response.AddHeader". AppendHeader causes an error that the browser can't show you because of the content type you just specified.

Other than that, it totally worked. 

Excel warned me that the content of the file I was about to open didn't match the filename extension, but it opened it up just fine, and behaved like any other spreadsheet! Great tip!